# swipe gesture not recognized if screen is not loaded in first in react native

Tags: react-native, components, gesture, native-base, stack-navigator

I am using [DeckSwiper](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components#deckSwiper) from native-base.

The swipe gesture is working well when the react screen is the initial route of my stack navigator.

But when I load it as a second view that is displayed after clicking a button thanks to : this.props.navigation.navigate('DeckSwipeView') :
Cards are displayed but I am not able to swipe them.

If you guys have any idea ?

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a modal to display the screen, which seems to not be handled by deckSwiper. It works when I only use stack navigation.